# /bin/sh evaluates string while Bash does not

Tags: bash, shell, echo, printf, dash

When running the script below, I get two different outputs, depending on whether or not the shell used is `sh` or `bash`:

```
regex(){
     echo 's/\(.* \)\(!\{0,1\}\)has(/\1\2MOCK_has(/g'
}

replace_builtins(){
    sed -e "$(regex)"
}

echo 'if !has(\"nvim\"): ' | replace_builtins
```

- **bash**: `if !MOCK_has(\"nvim\"):`
- **sh**: `??MOCK_has(\"nvim\"):`

(those question marks were originally copied verbatim from the terminal, but disappeared when I saved the post. It's essentially non-printable characters)

I would like to know what is happening when running in POSIX sh mode that explains this phenomena.

EDIT: for bonus points explain why this also happens in Bash when substituting `echo` for `printf` in the `regex` function:

```
     printf 's/\(.* \)\(!\{0,1\}\)has(/\1\2MOCK_has(/g'
```

Comment: `yash` prints `if !MOCK_has(\"nvim\"):`, just like Bash. When I run it with `dash` I get `MOCK_has(\"nvim\"):` - no non-printable characters. What really is `sh` that you're using?

Comment: `/bin/sh -> dash`

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of "Why is printf better then echo". Here `\1` is unspecified behavior. Dash interprets it, Bash does not.

Comment: @Quasímodo Could you give me that link? There was no `printf` in the actual example script.

Comment: @Quasímodo Also, any idea how I can avoid it being interpreted by the shell? I just want to pass the generated regex to `sed`.

Comment: @oligofren: I get no non-printable characters, neither on Slackware nor on Ubuntu.

Comment: Of course, there you go: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819 It's such a canonical Q that I even forget to link it :)

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk : I will try to post a link to a runnable example

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk I am not sure what to say: when I copied the script verbatim and pasted it into `example.sh` and did `sh example.sh` and `dash example.sh` I got the `[][]MOCK_has(\"nvim"\)"` string both times. Maybe my environment variables make the difference, but I tried setting different LANG settings (it was LANG=C.UTF-8) without any effect (tried en_US.utf8 and POSIX). Full list: https://gist.github.com/fatso83/ede210b548f41d6514dc760c8012f85d

Comment: Yeah, I'll update the title. Sorry. I thought `/bin/sh` was essentially limiting any shell this was linked to some POSIX defined minimal behavior when it saw that $0 == "/bin/sh".

Comment: Yeah, I just now saw the comment where you mentioned it was Dash indeed. Anyway, this particular thing isn't really about feature-rich vs. plain POSIX shells: Dash processes escapes by default, my Busybox sh doesn't, Zsh and Yash do, and Ksh and Bash don't. Bash does have an option for it (`xpg_echo`), but it's different from the usual POSIX-compatibilty option, so Bash as `/bin/sh` is the same as Bash as `/bin/bash` here. (Confused yet?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is in the [POSIX specification for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> A string to be written to standard output. If the first operand is `-n`, or if any of the operands contain a <backslash> character, the results are implementation-defined.

POSIX mostly codified historical practice, and sometimes historical practice was not consistent. Some shells expand escape sequences in the arguments to `echo`, for example `\t` expands to a tab and `\1` expands to the character with byte value 1 (`^A`). Other shells treat backslash as an ordinary character.

The portable way to print an arbitrary string is with `printf`. `printf` always expands backslash escape sequences in its first argument (the format). To print a string literally, use

```
printf %s 's/\(.* \)\(!\{0,1\}\)has(/\1\2MOCK_has(/g'
```

To print a string literally and add a newline at the end, use

```
printf '%s\n' 's/\(.* \)\(!\{0,1\}\)has(/\1\2MOCK_has(/g'
```

Note that if the string is written in the shell script using a single-quoted literal, a single quote character needs to be written as `'\'''`. This is about the shell syntax, a completely different problem from printing a string literally.

Comment: And indeed, by replacing `printf <string>` with `printf "%s" <string>` all my problems did go away :) Now, off to mock vim builtins!

Comment: Your answer is wrong, it is just that dash is not POSIX compliant.

Comment: @schily It's POSIX-compliant (in this respect), but not XSI-compliant.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Linux claims UNIX compatibility and for this reason, POSIX compliance on Linux means POSIX/XSI compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You identifed an interesting problem...

The problem is missing POSIX compatibility in `dash`.

POSIX distincts bewteen a basic POSIX compatibility level for tiny embedded systems and larger systems (like e.g. Linux) that claim UNIX compatibility. In the latter case, the system needs to implement all so called XSI extensions.

An XSI compatible system would need to expand certain backslash escapes in `echo` arguments.

`bash` can be compiled to behave POSIX/XSI compliant (and this is e.g. done on Solaris and MacOS), but this is not done for the `bash` binary on Linux. If `bash` is compiled for POSIX/XSI compliance, it correctly handles backslash escapes for `echo` arguments and your example code would work with such a `bash` binary from Solaris or MacOS, because there is no POSIX/XSI escape sequence in your example code.

Since `bash` on Linux is not XSI compliant, it does not expand backlash escapes  for `echo` arguments at all and this is why your example code works with `bash` on Linux as well.

`dash` on the other side claims POSIX/XSI compliance and expands backslash escapes for `echo` arguments. If `dash` did implement POSIX/XSI compliance correctly, your example code did work with `dash` as well. This is because your example code does not contain any POSIX/XSI backslash escape sequence.

POSIX/XSI requires `echo` to expand:

```
\0nnn  for an octal number that represents the related character
```

Your example code contains the backslash sequences:

```
\1 for the first sed subexpression
```

and

```
\2 for the second sed subexpression
```

and this is not part of the POSIX/XSI `echo` escape sequences, so the builtin `echo` from a POSIX compliant shell is not permitted to expand them. `dash` however incorrectly expands `\1` and `\2` as octal numbers even tough this is forbidden by POSIX. This is why your example code fails with `dash`.

I recommend you to make a bug-report against `dash` and either wait for a fix, or to replace `echo arg` by `printf '%s\n' arg`. This works even with `dash` because the known bug with the builtin `printf` in `dash` does not affect your case.

So we can list the POSIX/XSI bugs from `dash` as:

- does not support multy-byte characters.
- expands `\nnn` in `echo` arguments even though this is forbidden
- does not expand `\nnn` in `printf` arguments even though this is required.